# creating an automatic logout page in php

Tags: php, session, timeout

i am trying to write a automatic `logout` script which seems to work but not to my expectations,i do not know what exactly im doing wrong,i want to put the `timeout.php` on every page so that when the user is idle it logs out automatically and redirects it to `login` page but when i put the `timeout.php` on for my add user page where admin adds users,its overriding the link for the add user page and putting a `login` page which is also not coming out nicely(i.e the form is getting out of its position)[image: it looks like this]

this is the timeout.php code

```
   <?php 
$_SESSION = 0;
if($_SESSION['session_count'] == 0) { 
$_SESSION['session_count'] = 1;
$_SESSION['session_start_time']=time();
} else {
$_SESSION['session_count'] = $_SESSION['session_count'] + 1;
}

$session_timeout = 10; //  (in sec)

$session_duration = time() - $_SESSION['session_start_time'];
if ($session_duration > $session_timeout) { 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION["expired"] = "yes";
header("Location: login.php"); // Redirect to Login Page
} else {
$_SESSION['session_start_time']=time();
}
?>
```

i want it to automatically logout and redirect itself to the login page with a message yoour session has expired and i want it to put it on every page without it disturbing the forms or overlapping the page

Comment: Have you tried using a polling javascript to check for activity (such as scrolling and mouse clicks) before redirecting? In any case, I recommend you check out [this](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) plugin.